# Getting __v_isRef”: true when using Vuex in composition function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

For some strange reason I'm getting this result when trying to use my `loginString()` function in my template. As far as I know, you don't need to use `.value` in templates.

> { “_dirty”: true, “__v_isRef”: true, “__v_isReadonly”: true }

Here is my code

**App.vue**

```
<template>
    <div>{{ language }}</div>
    <div>{{ login }}</div>
    <div>{{ loginString() }}</div> <!-- Problem is here -->
</template>

<script setup>
    import { computed } from 'vue'
    import store from './store.js'
    import useLanguage from './useLanguage.js'

    const { loginString } = useLanguage()

    let language = computed(() => store.state.language)
    let login = computed(() => store.state.languages[language.value]['translations']['Login'])
</script>
```

**and useLanguage.js**

```
import store from './store.js'
import { computed } from 'vue'

function useLanguage()
{
    function loginString()
    {
        let language = computed(() => store.state.language)
        let login = computed(() => store.state.languages[language.value]['translations']['Login'])

        return login
    }

    return { loginString }
}

export default useLanguage
```

**An my store.js**

```
import { createStore } from 'vuex'
 
export default createStore({
    state()
    {
        return {
            language: 'en',

            languages: {
                "es": {
                    "lang_short": "es",
                    "lang_long": "espanol",

                    "translations": {
                        "Login": "Benga, venga!",
                        "Welcome Back": "Opa! Muy amigos!",
                    }
                },

                "en": {
                    "lang_short": "en",
                    "lang_long": "english",

                    "translations": {
                        "Login": "login",
                        "Welcome Back": "Welcome",
                    }
                },
            },
        }
    },
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Only root level `ref`s returned from `setup()` are automatically unwrapped - see this [issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-next/issues/803) and corresponding [commit](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-next/pull/1682)

> Template auto ref unwrapping for setup() return object is now applied only to the root level refs.

Your `loginString` returned from `setup` is a function, not `ref` so if that function returns `ref`/`computed`, you must use `loginString().value` in template...

Answer (score 0):

Looking around the Vue 3 docs, I found the solution. I needed to use `.value` or `unref` in order to unwrap the ref and get the actual value

```
import store from './store.js'
import { computed } from 'vue'

function useLanguage()
{
    function lang(string)
    {
        let language = computed(() => store.state.language)
        let translation = computed(() => store.state.languages[language.value]['translations'][string])

        return translation.value
    }

    return { lang }
}

export default useLanguage
```